# Вопросы про pythonw

Tags: python, python-3.x

Недавно узнал про запуск файлов с помощью команды `pythonw`, но не нашел интересующие меня вопросы:

1. Данная команда интерпретирует файл в скрытом шелле или где то в другом месте? В чем различия между `pythonw` и `python`?
2. После завершение программы шелл остается открытым? Нужно ли его закрывать самостоятельно внутри кода?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pythonw` не открывает окно консоли, используется в основном для работы с GUI либо в фоновом режиме. Закрывается при завершении программы.

Пример: PyQt при запуске через `python` всегда будет иметь консоль на фоне. Через `pythonw` будет только окно PyQt.

Пример 2 сервер работающий в фоне без отрисовки консоли. Нужно проработать условие закрытия или закрывать через диспетчер так как взаимодействовать с ним сложнее в таком режиме.